# Is there a way to press once to start and a second time to end bulb mode on a Canon Rebel T3?

Tags: canon, long-exposure, camera-settings, camera-controls, bulb-mode

I have a Canon Rebel T3. While the shutter speed is set to bulb, can I set it that so when I press the shutter release, it will open, and then press again to close? As it is now I have to continuously hold the shutter down. It would be nice to take photos longer than 30s.

Comment: You cannot normally do that from the camera's body (I'm talking here about the most camera models).
You might want to try a cable release or remote trigger.
Manually triggering the shutter while on BULB, will ALWAYS cause camera shakes.

Answer (score 3):

The canon 760D has bulb function that you have to hold down, so if I want to do a long exposure I have a wired remote, Shoot RS- 60E3 Wired Remote £3.59, that will lock open the shutter until you release it, if you go back and press the shutter button to close the shutter you could move the camera and spoil your shot.

Answer (score 0):

One click to open and another click to close shutter is named Time Mode (T mode). Some cameras offer it (more so in the old days, new users don't know, don't care).  Otherwise, most any remote shutter release offers a slide switch to hold it open until you change it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. Set the touch screen on, press the screen amd your picture will start. You will only have to press the button/screen when you want it to stop.